# Why does changing a CSS class name break the styles?

Tags: css, django, sass, zurb-foundation

This one is a real head-scratcher for me.

I'm using Zurb Foundation with SASS, and a Django dev server. The issue is this:

I have a SCSS file with some selectors, and they work as desired; however, if I change the *name* of the class in both the SCSS and the HTML, the elements under that class no longer render.

```css
// the_styles.scss
.ad-box {
   @include panel();
   border: none;

   .ad {
      width: 728px;
      height: 240px;
      border: 1px solid #00f;
   }
}
```

```html
<!-- the_page.html -->
<div class="large-12 columns ad-box ">
   <div class="ad small-centered columns">
      <span style="font-size:21px;color:#000000;width:728px;height:728px;line-height:240px">728
         <small style="font-size:0.8em">x</small> 240
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

produces what I want:

[image: Properly Rendered Webpage]

*but!* if I change, in both files, the class `ad` to `banner-ad` I get this undesirable result:

[image: Not at all what I wanted!]

More specifically, when I "change, in both files, the class" I mean that I

1. Change in `the_styles.scss` : `.ad {` --> `.banner-ad {`
2. Change in `the_page.html` : `class="ad small-centered columns"` --> `class="banner-ad small-centered columns"`
3. Recompile SASS
4. reload the page in Chrome

Furthermore, I have also tried shutting down the development server before doing the steps above, and starting it up before #4, to no noticeable change in behavior.

Changing the class name back to `ad` does then work again.

I do understand that there are a number of intermediaries going on here, like Django templates, the fabric task to recompile SASS, etc. so if I haven't isolated this enough, do let me know. As it is, I am completely baffled.

Comment: When in Chrome after changing `ad` to `banner-ad`, did you check the development tools to inspect the generated CSS ? I think your HTML uses the `banner-ad` class, but your CSS is stuck to `ad` (whether because in Chrome cache or because not updated by your compilation script)

Comment: Try to clear your cache and reload the page..

Comment: Do you have an ad blocker? It's quite possible that the name "banner-ad" triggers different blocking rules than "ad".

Comment: @MrLister, well done! That's it--disable ABP on the site, reload and the banner-ad class renders as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MrLister--

The problem is AdBlockPlus, which was blocking the element--Looking at the filter list [here](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt) it's apparent that `banner-ad` and many other variations I thought of were automatically filtered by the ad blocker.